# Round robin on iterable

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the following, simple round-robin implementation:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

class RoundRobin:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = set(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        for value in chain.from_iterable(repeat(self._iterable)):
            yield value
```

Example usage:

```
machines = ['test1', 'test2', 
            'test3', 'test4']
rr_machines = RoundRobin(machines)
for machine in rr_machines:
   # Do something
   pass
```

While this works, I was wondering if there was a way to modify the iterable in the `RoundRobin` class that would also impact existing iterators.

E.g. suppose that while I'm consuming values from the iterator, one of the machines from the set has become unavailable, and I want to prevent it from being returned.

The only solution I could think of was to implement a separate `Iterator` class. Of course, that still leave the question what to do when all machines have become unavailable and no more values can be returned (`StopIteration` exception?).

Comment: Why can't you use `continue` statement when the machine becomes unavailable?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh True, but consider (though I admit not having specified that in my question) that there may be several threads using the RR code, and I'd like to signal my RR class that one of the machines has become unavailable, without having to inform each thread individually. (I'm not sure if that made it more clear actually…)

Comment: In that case you have a static variable for the class, which may be a set of unavailable machines, and add the machine number to the set before the continue statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itertools' `repeat` makes a copy of the underlying iterator, in this case, your `set` containing the elements.

It is a mater of creating another implementation of `repeat` which would re-create such a copy at each iteration of the whole set. That is possible, because in this case, we know the iterator to be repeated is a container, while `itertools.repeat` has to work with any iterator (and so, remember the values from the first iteration):

```
def mutable_repeat(container):
    while True:
        for item in container.copy():
            yield item
```

Just using this in place of repeat, allows you to make "on the fly" changes to your `self._iterable` set, and new values can be added/removed from that set. (Although a removed value most likely will be issued one last time before being removed)

If you need to guard against issuing a removed value even once, you can easily guard against it by  adding some more logic to the whole thing - 
instead of iteracting with `self._iterable` directly from outside your class, you could do:

```
class RoundRobin:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = set(iterable)
        self._removed = set()

    def __iter__(self):
        for value in chain.from_iterable(self.repeat()):
            yield value

    def remove(self, item):
        self._removed.add(item)
        self._iterable.remove(item)

    def add(self, item):
        self._iterable.add(item)

    def repeat(self):
        while True:
            for item in self._iterable.copy():
                if not item in self._removed:
                    yield item
            self._removed = set()
```